# After modifying dashboard SAQL in template downstream apps fail to create

Tags: managed-package, einstein-analytics, analytics, isv, saql

**What we have done:**

1. Created a trivial Einstein *Analytics app* with the most simple *dataflow* and dashboard.
2. Created a **template** for this app
3. Successfully created a (**downstream**) app from this template (to prove that our stuff works)
4. Went back to the dashboard and modified its **SAQL** (add blank + remove it)
5. Updated the template
6. Tried to create a new app from that template which failed with

> Generation of resource type [dashboardTemplate], label [TestD] failed.
>   LastModifiedBy.SmallPhotoUrl FROM EdgeMart WHERE Id =
>   '${App.Datasets.MyData.Id}' ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:413 invalid ID
>   field: ${App.Datasets.MyData.Id}  Creating application [t2] failed.

**Why that?!?** We don't use Edgemart at all. We did not change a single bit (besides the timestamp) SAQL was the same after the save.

We opened a **support case #20441598** with support but have hope they will help us before xmas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were told by support that we are doing it the right way, but there is a **bug** that will be **fixed with Winter'19**.

For a more lengthy discussion on what was supposed to be the problem but then was not see this thread in the Success Community: https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00003nTUGz